# How to Get Security Roles in CRM 2011 Using JavaScript?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I need to get the security roles which are associated to the current user in CRM Online.  How do I do this using JavaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `Xrm.Page.context.getUserRoles()` function.

Comment: If i use this I can get the ID of the userrole which means i get the number not a name of the user role.

Comment: @V.V you can always perform an ODATA call to get the id.  Using this blog, you can see what entities you'll need to interact with, but since it's for C#, you won't be able to use it as is: http://arvindcsit.wordpress.com/crm-learning/retrieve-the-roles-for-a-user/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Is there any possible way to do this from script?

Comment: Yes, the easiest way is with an OData call.  If you've never made an OData call before in CRM, consider asking a new question, "How do I get the Id of a role by role namevia JavaScript in CRM 2011?